# Задача китайского почтальона. Поиск Эйлерового цикла

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, java-8

В вузе задали решить задачу Китайского почтальона.Вот алгоритм её решения.

1. Смотрим Эйлеровый ли граф нам попался. Если да переходим к пункту (5).
2. Строим матрицу расстояний для графов с нечётными степенями вершин.
3. Строим минимальные паросочетания.
4. У найденных пар строим мнимые пути.Теперь наш граф Эйлеровый.
5. Находим Эйлеровый цикл это и будет ответ в нашей задачи.
   Проблема с 5 пунктом, если граф изначально был не Эйлеровый. Выводит не понятный для меня путь. Пытался сам найти ошибку ничего не вышло.
   Матрицу смежности задаю в виде 
   0 1 1 0
   1 0 1 1
   1 1 0 2
   0 2 1 0
   Где цифры больше 0 означают количество путей, в том числе и мнимых.При такой матрице выводятся значения
   01133210

   ```
    private List<Integer> eilerPath(int[][] matrixAdjacency) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int v = 0;
        int u;
        int edge;
        stack.push(v);
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            edge = findAdjacencyVertex(matrixAdjacency, stack.peek());
            if (edge == -1) {
                list.add(stack.pop());
            } else {
                u = edge;
                matrixAdjacency[stack.peek()][u]--;
                matrixAdjacency[u][stack.peek()]--;
                stack.push(u);
            }
        }
    return list;
    }

    private int findAdjacencyVertex(int[][] matrixAdjacency, int edge) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixAdjacency.length; i++) {
            if (matrixAdjacency[edge][i] > 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
   ```

Comment: Кажется, это: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/assignment_hungary

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли минимальное паросочетание я уже нашёл. Проблема построить Эйлеров цикл с этим паросочетанием.

Comment: Просто добавить в граф новые рёбра и найти эйлеров цикл.

Comment: Я же написал что добавил мнимые пути. Это в матрице смежности обозначено как 2. Проблема в том что данный алгоритм работает не правильно с мнимыми путями и выводит некорректный Эйлеровый цикл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм полностью работает. Нашёл у себя ошибку в другом месте кода. Не совсем правильно строилась матрица смежности с мнимыми путями. В некоторых местах просто их не добавляла из-за чего возникали пути с нечётным количеством рёбер.